# What Protocol is Azure Data Factory Copy Activity using?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to copy data through a self hosted Integration Runtime using Azure Data Factory. Since we hav databases on prem (sql, postgress, oracle) with several firewalls in between. I'm wondering what Protocol the Linked Service is using for the copy activity? Is it TCP?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mostly https. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-movement-security-considerations#frequently-asked-questions):

**What are the port requirements for the self-hosted integration runtime to work?**

> The self-hosted integration runtime makes HTTP-based connections to access the internet. The outbound ports 443 must be opened for the self-hosted integration runtime to make this connection. Open inbound port 8060 only at the machine level (not the corporate firewall level) for credential manager application. If Azure SQL Database or Azure Synapse Analytics is used as the source or the destination, you need to open port 1433 as well.

Also, in addition to the [default ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-movement-security-considerations#firewall-requirements-for-on-premisesprivate-network), port 1433 needs to be opened in the following scenario.

> Required only when you copy from or to Azure SQL Database or Azure Synapse Analytics and optional otherwise. Use the staged-copy feature to copy data to SQL Database or Azure Synapse Analytics without opening port 1433.

Comment: Hi, as far as I understand this is for outgoing connection. It needs to connect with Azure Relay. But is it also the case when copying data? For example a Oracle database on prem. I have to specify the host IP and port: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-oracle?tabs=data-factory . Does TCP needs to be opened for the copying of data or is really https enough?